# Hit and miss ration in cache and average time calculation

Tags: memory, computer-science, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to solve a objective type question , came In examination. I actually don't know the right answer, and don't know how to get it , need your help. Thank you .

**Question :**
In a certain system the main memory access time is 100 ns. The cache is 10 time faster than the main memory and uses the write though protocol. If the hit ratio for read request is 0.92 and 85% of the memory requests generated by the CPU are for read, the remaining being for write; then the average time consideration both read and write requests is

a) 14.62ns

b) 348.47ns

c) 29.62ns

d) 296.2ns

**My work ::::**

Well, memory access time               = 100ns

cache access time would be  =  10 ns          (10 time faster)

```
In order to find avg time we have a formula

Tavg = hc+(1-h)M

   where h = hit rate
     (1-h) = miss rate
       c   = time to access information from cache
        M  = miss penalty  (time to access main memory)
```

Write through operation : cache location and main memory location is updated simultaneously.

It is given that 85% request generated by CPU is read request and 15% is write request.

```
Tavg = 0.85(avg time for read request)+ 0.15(avg time for write request)
     = 0.85(0.92*10+0.08*100)+0.15(avg time for write request)
```

//* 0.92 is  a hit  ratio for read request  ,  but hit ratio for write request is not given ??

If I assume that hit hit ratio for write request is same as hit ratio for read request then,

```
  = 0.85(0.92*10+0.08*100)+0.15(0.92*(10+100)+0.08*100)
  =31 ns
```

If I assume that hit ratio is 0% for write request then,

```
  = 0.85(0.92*10+0.08*100)+0.15(0*110+1*100)
  =29.62 ns
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second assumption is correct.

With the write-through cache, it writes immediately the modified blocks to memory and then onto disk. Since no disk access time is given, it is eliminated from the equation. My notations are little different, but I will post it that way for future readers. I used the notation given in **William Stallings** *Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles*.

**Given:**

```
Tm = 100ns
Tc = 10ns /* 10x faster than Tm */ 
Hr = 0.92 /* Hit rate reading */
85% reading => 15% of the time writing
```

**Solution:**

```
The effective access time for reading:
Te_r = Hr * Tc + (1-Hr)Tm = 0.92*10 + (1 - 0.92)100 = 9.2 + 8 = 17.2

The effective access time for writing, is determined from the Hit rate Hw,
which is always 0, because the data must be immediately written onto the 
memory.
Te_w = Hw * Tc + (1-Hw)Tm = 0*10 + (1 - 0)100 = 100

Taking into account the percentage:
0.85*17.2 + 0.15*100 = 14.62 + 15 = 29.62

                                                                    Q.E.D
```

Comment: Why do you mention anything about disk?  The question doesn't say the memory is backed by disk, so you should assume it isn't.  e.g. a `MAP_PRIVATE` (like the data section of an executable) or `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (malloc, or the bss section) mapping.  Normal OSes don't write dirty anonymous pages to swap unless there's memory pressure, even if they reserve enough swap to avoid overcommit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, I assumed exactly that. However, the write-through cache writes to the backing storage and I thought that with "memory" was meant the *inboard main memory*, which is volatile. That's why as common backing storage, I thought of the disk. But still I didn't assume it in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Avg access time considering only read = 0.92*10 + 0.08*100 = 17.2 ns.

Avg access time considering only write = 100 ns (because in write through you have to go back to memory to update even if it is a hit or miss. if you assume hit ratio = 0.5 and miss = 0.5 then 0.5*100 + 0.5*100 = 1*100)

So, total access time for both read and write would be - 0.85*17.2 + 0.15*100 = 14.62 + 15 = 29.62 ns

**you cant assume hit ratio for write same as hit ratio for read. for write request (write through) whatever will be the case, you have to write back in the memory. so the write access time will be equal to memory access time.

Answer (score 0):

In case of write through policy and when data is directly read from main memory when cache miss occurs,

```
Tavg(for write)=Hw*Tm +(1-Hw)*Tm = Tm
```

Hw=hit ratio for write, Tm=Time to access main memory

in this formula, in both cases of cache hit & miss, we can update and read data simultaneously in Tm time itself, since usually Tm>>Tc. So Tc for reading can be ignored.

Hence you dont need to know hit ratio for write for this question. and the answer would be 29.62ns